# Does this SQL statement look right?

Tags: sql

I wondering is what I am doing right.

```
select distinct 
    Departments.Department_No, Departments.Department_Name 
from 
    Departments 
join 
    Employees on Departments.Department_No = Employees.Department_No
join 
    Jobs on Jobs.Job_ID = Employees.Job_ID
where  
    Departments.Department_No not in (select distinct Department_No 
                                      from Employees 
                                      where Employees.Job_ID like '%SA_REP%');
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? and what do want as result ?

Comment: have you tried executing it?

Comment: Does it give you the right results?  What _specifically_ are you concerned about?

Comment: Why are you joining onto employees and jobs but not using any columns from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to display distinct values of `Department Number` and `Department Name`
- You join `Employees` table with `Department` on `Department Number`
- You join `Jobs` table with `Employees` on `Job ID`
- You filter the result by excluding those `Department Numbers` of the *entire* `Employee` table that have a `Job ID` matching the pattern `%SA_REP%`

In my opinion you don't need

- the join with the `Jobs` table
- the join with the `Employees` table
- you could maybe see if one of the other users' suggestions can bring performance improvement

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT departments.department_no, 
                departments.department_name 
FROM   departments 
WHERE  departments.department_no NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT department_no 
                                         FROM   employees 
                                         WHERE  employees.job_id LIKE '%SA_REP%' 
                                        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this using `NOT EXISTS` instead of using a `NOT IN` subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     d.Department_No
    ,d.Department_Name
FROM Departments d
JOIN Employees e ON d.Department_No = e.Department_No
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
  (select 1
     from Employees e1
    where e1.Job_ID like '%SA_REP%'
    AND e1.Department_No = e.Department_No);
```

Comment: That changes the semantics. The query in the OP won't bring back a department if it has *any* employees with `Job_ID like '%SA_REP%'` - this will still bring the department back unless *all* employees match that condition.

Comment: @MartinSmith I suppose you are right. I didn't think it like that. I have update my solution to use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate where condition without "in".
And you don't need to fetch date from "Jobs" - you don't use it

```
Select distinct Departments.Department_No, Departments.Department_Name 
from Departments 
Join Employees on Departments.Department_No = Employees.Department_No
where  Employees.Job_ID not  like '%SA_REP%';
```